# How do I run specific functions based on tags in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a test framework that will run hundreds of tests.  Each of these tests has been written as an independent function.  Currently, I have my main function run each of these tests one-by-one.  What I would like to make is a system that uses tags.  For example, I want to be able to run all the tests with the 'WiFi' tag or run all the tests that have a 'notifications' tag.

I have tried looking up how to do this, but all I can find are articles that talk about [tag dispatching](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/04/27/tag-dispatching/) which doesn't help me.  Maybe a tag isn't what I need here?

Not sure if this matters but I'm writing in c++11 on a Mac, and I'm using VS Code.

btw I'm new to stack overflow, so sorry if I messed anything up.  Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I would use multiple tags per function. For example, there is a function that would need 'WiFi' and 'Network' tags, and another that would need 'Haptic', 'Notification', and 'Network' tags.

Comment: Sounds like you need a map of `std::map<some_type_of_tag_type, function_pointer_or_std::function>` and that way you can iterate the map to get all of one type of tag functions.

Comment: I thought about using a map, but to do that, I would need a new map for each tag, which seems like an inelegant approach. I anticipate having hundreds of tests, and possibly 20-30 tags. It's a good idea, but I'm hoping there is a better way.

Comment: You can make your "tag" a string.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. If the tag was a string, I would still have lots of huge maps, which would become a challenge to keep updated.

Comment: Do you want to be able to tag a function with multiple tags, or will it be one tag per function?

Comment: Multiple tags per function. I'll edit my question to include that. For example, there is a function that would need 'WiFi' and 'Network' tags, and another that would need 'Haptic', 'Notification', and 'Network' tags.

Comment: Any chance you can use C++14?

Comment: _"I would need a new map for each tag"_ I don't agree. At worst, you need a multimap from "tag" to functions, and a multimap from functions to "tag" if you need reverse lookup too. Both of those are pretty trivial.

Comment: @NathanOliver I should be able to. Is there something there that can help?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I haven't heard of a multimap. I'll look into that. Do you have any good examples I can look at?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ah it looks like a multimap is just a regular map with more than one value per key. Interesting. I might be able to use that!

Comment: Without a multimap, a `map<Tag, vector<Function>>` would still be easy :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your research has gone badly is that "tag" is a very broad, general term that doesn't really describe what you're doing.

Fundamentally, you're trying to map two pieces of data together; that's it really. Doesn't matter whether one of those pieces (your "tag") is an integer, an enum member, a string, a class instance or anything else.

You've said *"I would need a new map for each tag"*, but I don't agree. You only need a multimap from "tag" to functions (and, at worst, another multimap from functions to "tag" if you need reverse lookup too). These are pretty trivial.

```
enum class Tag
{
   WiFi,
   Haptic,
   Network,
   Notification
};

using Function = std::function<void()>;  // or whatever it is

std::multimap<Tag, Function> tagLookup;

void BindTag(const Tag tag, Function func)
{
   tagLookup.emplace(tag, std::move(func));  // I'm using move out of habit
}

void RunFuncsForTag(const Tag tag)
{
   auto [start, end] = tagLookup.equal_range(tag);
   for (auto it = start; it != end; ++it)
   {
      const Function& func = it->second;
      func();
   }
}

int main()
{
   BindTag(...);
   BindTag(...);

   RunFuncsForTag(tag);
}
```

Admittedly, if you don't want lots of copies of your `std::function`, there's some more work to do (you could store them in another container and have some other mapping to do that lookup to each function stored once), but the basic data storage principle here is fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me understand my problem a lot better, as well as giving me a solution.

Comment: I would use instead `std::unordered_multimap`, as the order between different tags doesn't matter. But that would hardly make any practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with multimap, but you can also keep it simple with just one container with all the tests:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <class E> auto as_underlying(E e) -> std::underlying_type_t<E>
{ return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<E>>(e); }

enum class Tag : unsigned {
    WiFi = 0x01u,
    Network = 0x02u,
    Haptic = 0x04u,
    Notification = 0x08u,
};

auto operator|(Tag lhs, Tag rhs) -> Tag
{
    return Tag{as_underlying(lhs) | as_underlying(rhs)};
}

struct Test
{
    using F = bool();

    Tag tag;
    F* test; // or std::function

    bool has_tag(Tag tag_to_check) const
    {
        return as_underlying(tag) & as_underlying(tag_to_check);
    }

    bool operator()() const { return test(); }
};

template <class Cont>
auto run_by_tag(const Cont& tests, Tag tag)
{
    for (const auto& test : tests)
    {
        if (test.has_tag(tag))
        {
            test();
        }
    }
}

auto test()
{
    std::vector<Test> tests{
        Test{Tag::WiFi | Tag::Network, [] { return true;}},
        Test{Tag::Haptic | Tag::Notification | Tag::Network, [] { return false; }},
        Test{Tag::Notification, [] { return true;}}
    };

    run_by_tag(tests, Tag::WiFi);
    run_by_tag(tests, Tag::Notification);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I can agree that this is simpler.